# ASP.NET MVC Bundling wrong Bootstrap version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have an issue where the Bundling in MVC4 in production is somehow bundling an older version of Bootstrap that I no-longer have in my project.

I updated the version of Bootstrap as I wanted to use some Glyphicons that the old version in my project didn't support.

Running locally in debug or release mode, all of the Glyphicons show as expected, but once deployed to production (using msbuild to deploye to Azure Web App), the newer Glyphicons are missing, and the minified+bundled css file is missing references to the newer Gyphicons - it's essentially an older version of bootstrap.css

This is my RegisterBundles method:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.UseCdn = false;

        // Clear out the list and add back the ones we want to ignore.
        // Don't add back .debug.js.
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
        bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
        bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*intellisense.js");

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/style/global").Include(
            "~/Content/css/lib/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/css/global.css"));
    }
```

Then I'm using...

```
@Styles.Render("~/style/global")
```

To include the styles.

Comment: Can you confirm that the newer versions do indeed exist on your Azure web app?

Comment: Yes, if I hit /Content/css/lib/bootstrap.css the newer version does indeed download.

Comment: Just as an experiment try this: `bundles.ResetAll();       BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`  before `bundles.Add(...)`

Comment: Can't test deploying until tonight, but I'll try it then and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: That works, but setting EnableOptimizations = false obviously stops it bundling, so it's simply serving the raw css file.

Comment: The ResetAll() on its own seems to do the trick.  If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ResetAll()` method to clear and reset. More about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecollection.resetall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where my `ASP.NET MVC 5` application was still using an older version of `bootstrap.css (3.0)` even after I had removed the older bootstrap.css file from the project, and installed `Bootstrap 3.3.7` NuGet package.  When I ran the application and did "View Page Source" from the browser, then clicked the ***"/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"*** link, it **STILL** brought up the old bootstrap.css file content.

**I was baffled and messed with it for over an hour until I realized that the css page was cached.**  I figured this out because when I clicked the *"/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"* link to bring up the `bootstrap.css` then REFRESHED the page, it changed to my 3.3.7 version.

Anyway, I decided to post this response because maybe it would help someone else to understand that the issue could be because of caching.